# Error haskell: not in scope. What does that mean?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I started with Haskell today and all the functions I perform on ghci display this message. I just want to know why this is happening. 
I know there are a lot of questions about this, but this is a simple case and I need to understand this error in the beginning

```
function3 :: Int -> [Int]
function3 x = [a | a <- [1..x] mod a x == 0]
```

Comment: "Not in scope" means you are trying to use a name which is not defined in the place in which you are trying to use it. In this case, it happens because you left out a comma after `[1..x]`, and so your definition of `a` within the list comprehension doesn't work as it should. Change it to `[a | a <- [1..x], mod a x == 0]`

Comment: It help if you include whole GHCi error message in the question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Did error happen when you type the function type in GHCi?

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> function3 :: Int -> [Int]

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: function3 :: Int -> [Int]
Prelude>
```

If it is the case, you have to use multiple line input

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| function3 :: Int -> [Int]
Prelude| function3 x = [a | a <- [1..x], mod a x == 0]
Prelude| :}
```

And noted `,` before `mod`

Alternatively, for better workflow, you can save your code to a file and load in GHCi using [:load](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html)

```
$ cat tmp/functions.hs 
function3 :: Int -> [Int]
function3 x = [a | a <- [1..x], mod a x == 0]

$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l tmp/functions.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tmp/functions.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :t function3 
function3 :: Int -> [Int]
*Main>
```

Comment: In what case would `function3 :: Int -> [Int]` not throw an error in ghci ?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was trying to `:reload` my `.hs` file in ghci after opening a new session but doing `:load full_file_name.hs` solved the issue.